# Problems unsing Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pick out up url of the Git repo below but am having real trouble accessing it from Python.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string,"lxml")


    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-embed-close details-list-item-icon" 
    title="Source Code"></span>
    <a href="*https://github.com/UnitedBitcoin*" target="_blank" 
    rel="noopener">Source Code</a>
```

https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/united-bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20080428&end=20181211
[image]

I'm getting massive long list of urls when I am after the website, source code, and technical documents research link.

Comment: Thank you for providing sample data. However, you don't show any effort to actually solve the problem, e.g. you don't show what you tried to do with the ``soup`` object to obtain this url, and what errors you encountered while trying to obtain the URL yourself. Please read the library's documentation and look at basic examples of its usage, what you're trying to do is nothing complex. I've provided an answer below anyway: if it solves your problem, please mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work for me on the data you provided:

```
url = soup.find('a')['href']
```

And if you don't want the asterisks,

```
url = soup.find('a')['href'].strip('*')
```